# How to build and run SpringBoot Application as standalone executable jar in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot. In Visual Studio Code, I have to create a standalone jar executable which will print the list of people in sorted order by name, age and experience.

The `application.properties`: (this was already written in the question)

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The error is:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
user@workspacecz4z9k4rne7mr1fz:/projects/challenge$ mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestDemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ TestDemo >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ TestDemo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.384 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-09T07:02:57+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/348M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) on project TestDemo: /projects/challenge/target/classes/application.properties (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

On doing mvn -e it showed:

```
user@workspacecz4z9k4rne7mr1fz:/projects/challenge$ mvn -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.809 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-09T07:04:24+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/246M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:94)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

I have created Employee bean class, EmployeeService, EmployeeController and Demo Application classes.
Demo Application (in case its required):

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

I also saw in Debug Console (if this information is of any use):

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
```

Kindly suggest how to overcome the errors mentioned above.

Comment: it sounds like a file system permission issue. mvn -e doesnt work because you didnt specify a goal. This should work: "mvn -e spring-boot:run"

Comment: Your title says *"Visual Studio"* while your body text says *"Visual Studio Code"*. These two are completely unrelated software products. You should correct this.

Comment: just use packaging as jar in your pom.xml and mvn clean install

Comment: The error raising by mvn spring-boot:run is /projects/challenge/target/classes/application.properties (Permission denied). Can you check the permissions on /projects/challenge/target/classes folder.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a couple of erros and tips:

You have a "/projects/challenge/target/classes/application.properties (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]" erro. Make sure if you're using linux, that you'r allowed to make changes in this folder. If you not:

```
chmod 777 -R /projects/
```

Also, you're using the wrong command to install your application, you must first:

```
mvn clean install
```

And after:

```
java -jar /projects/challenge/target/YourJar.jar
```

Comment: On doing chmod -R /projects/ it showed "Operation not permitted". On mvn clean install I got: –     Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) on project TestDemo: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /projects/challenge/target/test-classes/com/example/demo/TestEmployee.class

Comment: in the chmod add sudo in the beggining